# Unity3D, Can't Click Button on Panel with Canvas Component

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Canvas with 3 child images and two Panels, in that order. The GameOverPanel has 2 text and 2 buttons on it.
In addition to the UI objects, there are a number of other GameObjects that come after the Canvas including the player. The player has a SpriteRenderer with the SortingLayer = "Default" and OrderInLayer = 1.
So far so good. Everything displays correctly.

Here's where the issue comes in; When the GameOverPanel is set to active it is behind the player which it shouldn't be. So to fix this, I added a Canvas component to the GameOverPanel and now it displays over the player. However, after adding the Canvas to the GameOverPanel, the buttons which are children of the Panel are no longer clickable.

If I make the buttons direct children of the Canvas, the buttons work fine.

BTW - I'm using Unity 2019 1.7

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You have to give the new (child) canvas a [`GraphicRaycaster`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.GraphicRaycaster.html) component.

Otherwise the (child) canvas won't have any raycast detection. This is an intended feature, so that non-interactive elements can be isolated from interactive ones.

Comment: thanks but the link is broken fyi, I updated but you may want to change it to something else idk just letting you know...